Oct2py __init_fltk__.oct failed (error 126)
Installed MINGW octave through MSYS2 and trying to use oct2py. Have the following error running any octave code:
Oct2PyError: Octave evaluation error:
error: opening the library 'C:\tools\msys64\mingw64\lib\octave\9.1.0\oct\x86_64-w64-mingw32\__init_fltk__.oct' failed (error 126): The specified module could not be found.
    error: called from:
    graphics_toolkit at line 94, column 5
    figure at line 96, column 7
    newplot at line 120, column 10
    plot3 at line 123, column 9

__init_fltk__.oct is presented in the directory. I guess that the error output is not full, because I can't see which module should be installed. Tried to look through this init file, but haven't found any module calls
